# Display progress percentage on Button text while call AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, button, progress

In ASP.NET AJAX, When I click a button, an expensive progress is call, about 100+ items are progress in a loop, one-by-one. While the progress is running, how do I display the percentage text on the Button's Text?

For Example:

```
protected void btn_ExpensiveProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < MyCollection.Count; i++)
     {
          double Percent = i/MyCollection.Count * 100;
          btn_ExpensiveProcess.Text = Percent + "% " + " Has Been Done";
     }
}
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646535/A-More-Efficient-AJAX-Progress-Bar-for-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

For a long running process on the server I have found that the easiest way to accomplish this is AJAX polling your server.

You will need to have some sort of indicator on the server, whether you store your progress in a database (number of records added) or in a text file. You will need to AJAX poll the server in a timed function until the long running process is complete. You can then update the button text in the success callback of your AJAX polling method.

Be wary to give your polling function enough time between calls so you don't create a huge queue.